# How to use setdiff on two vectors?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a vector A <- 1:2000 and another vector B with 100 randomly selected values from A. I now want a vector with all the 1900 values in A not in B. I tried to use setdiff(A,B) but this results in a vector C which is 100:2000. I do not quiet get why this is the case since when playing around with setdiff it does give me the right value. I.E setdiff(1:5,3:8)

Answer (score 1):

`setdiff` returns the unique values of the first vector not in the second.  If we need all the elements, we can use `%in%` with `!`

```
A[!A %in% B]
```

---

In the second example

```
setdiff(1:5, 3:8)
```

all these values are unique and thus it didn't matter.  There is also a package solution for this

```
library(vecsets)
vsetdiff(A, B)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, I tried this but I still do not get the right result. Even when using vsetdiff(A,B), I get as output a vector with 100:2000. For some reason, it treats B as a vector with values 1:100, when in reality its a vector with random numbers from 1:2000.

Comment: @NerloFota the functions work as expected i.e. it should return the values in 'A' that are not in 'B'.  What would be the output of `sum(!A %in% B)` which gives the count of 'A' values not in 'B'

Comment: @NerloFota Also, this assumes that both are integer vectors ie. not a floating point object.  In that case, the precision matters

Comment: I think I have figured out the issue. It does not recognise B as a proper vector?.   B <- sample(1:2000, 2000, replace=F). Do you know why B would not be "compatible" with setdiff?

Comment: @NerloFota it is always better to use `dput` to show the example so that we get the structure correctly.  Function behaviors differ with type

Comment: Sorry I do not get what you mean. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @NerloFota i just saw your code.  `B <- sample(1:2000, 2000, replace=FALSE)` when you specify the `size` as 2000, it returns all the elements from 1 to 2000 but in a different position, thus you get `setdiff(A, B)` to have no matches

Comment: @NerloFota just check `sample(1:6, 6, replace = FALSE)` i.e. you are saying that elements shsould not be repeated, with `replace = FALSE`, thus the number of unique elements will be 6 here

Comment: My bad,  'B <- sample(1:2000, 100, replace=FALSE)' is what I actually have in R. nonetheless setdiff treats this as a vector with 1:100

Comment: @NerloFota I get 1900 `length(setdiff(A, B))
[1] 1900`

Comment: Yes, I get the same length, but the values of setdiff(A, B) are not correct.

Comment: @NerloFota what do you meant by that?  I get `any(setdiff(A, B) %in% B)#
[1] FALSE`

Comment: never mind I was able to fix it. Thank you anyways